# there is a performance gap between distros?

Tags: linux, performance, distributions

I am new to linux. Now i have tried a bunch of distros, like debian ubuntu fedora and arch. I was wondering which distro offers the best performance. For reference my machine is laptop(huawei matebook d15) with an i5-1135g7 and 8gb of ram. I tipically code in python and use blender for 3d modelling/render. for this workloads whic distro is recommended?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The performance difference between distributions could be very large. E.g. you could check this:

- https://www.phoronix.com/review/h1-2022-linux/8
- https://www.phoronix.com/review/xeon-max-linux-software/5

At the same time it's worth noting that e.g. Clear Linux is not in general something I'd recommend to use on a daily basis. It's a rolling distro with not a lot of users, so if you're going to use it, you're more likely to hit bugs, as there's not enough testing/QC/QA.

I'd recommend using something tried and tested, e.g. Fedora or Ubuntu and if you need the absolute maximum performance, you could rebuild the applications you use manually with the "best" compiler optimization flags, not limited to `-march=native`, `-O3`/`-Ofast` (potentially unsafe), `-flto=auto` and you could even employ PGO (profile guided optimizations) for additional performance. This way you'll get the system that is stable but is the fastest at the tasks you run.

Comment: You're quoting a test for a modern servers with a dual-socket server processor, 512 GB or RAM and 160 or 224 CPU threads with 60 MB or 112 MB caches. Thinking this has any resemblance to what that would see on a consumer laptop with 8 threads, a total of 8MB cache and 8GB RAM, and have any relevance to a laptop use case, especially as described by the question, is, let's call it, *creative*.

Comment: The benchmarks run on these machines are financial math simulations, searching solutions for non-linear Navier-Stokes problems, heavily distributed raytracing problems, large-scale molecular dynamics… in other words, things where you really would want to use such a large server, and where the cross-socket and memory bandwidth really matters. Sure, rendering a scene in Blender is also a CPU-heavy task, but on a laptop really limited by other factors.

Comment: You're posting a highly misleading claim if you can only back up "it makes a significant performance difference which distro you use" by HPC-typical payloads on number cruncher servers. "The paint you use to paint your car's rear has a large influence on performance, as shown by these benchmark for surface smoothness on fighter yets" makes about as much sense!

Comment: These are CPU bound benchmarks and yes, Phoronix has tested Clear Linux on normal desktops/laptops and also shown quite a performance difference. Thank you for 1) downvoting, Marcus 2) failing to accept reality 3) trying to portray data as invalid because "big PCs" have been used for testing. Three messages trying to slander, belittle and insult me. Meanwhile the OP has picked this answer as valid. Great you did zero research on the topic and just dumped your opinion as valid. The OP is interested in CPU heavy tasks otherwise they wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: The OP wrote: *"I tipically code in python and use blender for **3d modelling/render**. for this workloads whic distro is recommended?"* And you in your comments say Blender is an ... **invalid** benchmark? Like really? Oh boy. I'd be embarrassed but you can go ahead and find ways to expel me from this website. **And of course you've not run any benchmarks** and just made a blanket statement. *A **highly** misleading claim*. That's an egregious insult, Mr. Marcus. I mean Michael Larabell ran hundreds of tests, showed a serious performance gap exists and you just say it's all invalid? Whoa.

Comment: You can extract more performance from software by using more performance complication flags for GCC and profiling, is this also **invalid**, Mr. Markus? Where do you draw the line? You said **proven benchmark data is invalid**, can you also say my advice is invalid as well? Amazing. It's just amazing.

Comment: I don't say those benchmarks are invalid. I say extrapolating from benchmarks on giant HPC servers to a laptop computer is nonsensical, and I explicitly pointed out that you should, if you have benchmarks that described more similar hardware, refer to these. I also explicitly referred to "CPU bounded" not meaning the same for these workloads on a > 128 core machine as on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There's no meaningful difference in performance between these choices – in the end, all three ship the same software, built in very nearly identical ways.

The only differences might be

1. the up-to-dateness of kernel and drivers (which makes little difference for a laptop released 3 years ago – all these distros will be fine). Still, the slightly more modern kernel of Fedora or Arch would potentially be an advantage in very specific situations
2. the *ease* at which you can install proprietary graphics cards drivers (Nvidia, mostly), but this doesn't apply to your hardware. And "ease" is an extremely subjective term.

I'd argue that you'll be best served with a Linux distro that the most people use, and which has good stability guarantees. According to these (entirely personal) criteria, Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora play in the same league, and Arch is more of a rapidly evolving, slightly more experimental thing.

So, pick any of Ubuntu, debian or Fedora. I personally like the Fedora installer more than the debian or Ubuntu one. That is an extremely weak argument, but it's what I'd go with. If you want ideally set up your system and then only fundamentally the operating system every two or four years, go with the current Ubuntu LTS (that's Ubuntu 22.04 LTS at the time of writing).

I'd not recommend Arch to a beginner. But again, that's *extremely* subjective. If you tested arch and found administrating it easy, you might simply be different than me (and that's totally OK).

Comment: To the above distributions I will add RedHat Enterprise Linux, which is free for development. and it have 10 years support cycle.

Comment: I'd explicitly not add that as a beginner friendly distro. The support you get is kind of meaningless in a non-corporate centrally-managed setting, and for progressively more software, RHEL removes end user applications from its support envelope and pushes them out to EPEL; this by now encompasses standard but complex software like Libreoffice, meaning that you get the lack of commercial support guarantees of community distros with the annoyance of corporate license management. I don't see any win for a private user in that.

Comment: Marcus, do not talk about support, because for Debian, Ubuntu, etc. you do not have official support (if you do not pay).

Comment: you don't have any support (in the sense of assistance) for RHEL either if you do not pay. That's no different. And with Debian having LTS releases, and Ubuntu also, you get the same promise of software maintenance these days, if not even longer – or have you already forgotten how short the RHEL8 lifecycle has become?

Comment: So no formal support for ANY of the distributions. In this case I do not see any difference and RHEL should in the list. BTW Fedora is more like test-bed and I will not recommend it for enduser.

Comment: no, RHEL should not be in the list of beginner-friendly distros, because forcing a beginner to activate their license (for literally no benefit), add EPEL and install *especially* unsupported software for standard tasks is nonsensical. All the other distros at least treat libreoffice as first-class citizen, for example! Also, my list, my rules ;) And: Fedora has *very* long ago stopped being RHEL's testbed.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; RHEL is/might be a good choice for a company with an IT department, which is taking advantage of the management facilities that RHEL brings. But as a standalone, everything-is-the-user's-problem distro? Simply not the target audience.